# C++ reduce repetitions of code for similar classes

Tags: c++, strings, template

I have the following two classes to make appending `string`s - and `wstring`s respectively - easier:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class StringBuilder
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    StringBuilder& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        this->stream << t;
        return *this;
    }

    operator std::string() const;

private:
    std::ostringstream stream;
};

StringBuilder::operator std::string() const
{
    return this->stream.str();
}

class WStringBuilder
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    WStringBuilder& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        this->stream << t;
        return *this;
    }

    explicit operator std::wstring() const;

private:
    std::wstringstream stream;
};

WStringBuilder::operator std::wstring() const 
{
    return this->stream.str();
}
```

Now, as you see, pretty much all of the code (except for the concrete `string` and `stringstream` types) is **repeated**, especially the operators.

The question is:

- **Is there any way to reduce the duplicated code?** I thought about a base class, templates and specialization, but the problem is I don't know how to determine the correct `stringstream` type depending on the `string` type then.

Comment: Small side point -- don't use `wstring`. It's a bad attempt at Unicode support, and should be phased out wherever possible. If you _have_ to communicate with an API that takes it, convert it there. See http://utf8everywhere.org/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is. In fact, a very nice way to solve this code redundancy issue comes to mind if you consider that `std::string` is a just type alias for `std::basic_string<char>` and `std::wstring` an alias for `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`. Likewise, `std::stringstream` and `std::wstringstream` are also just aliases for `std::basic_stringstream<char>` and `std::basic_stringstream<wchar_t>`, respectively. This allows for an easy template-based approach to the problem.

What really suggests itself to me is keeping this alias-of-template-base-type pattern from the STL (although there may be other valid approaches as well), an implementation of which could look something like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

namespace impl {

    template <typename CharType>
    class StringBuilderImpl {

        std::basic_stringstream<CharType> stream;

        public:
        template <typename T>
        StringBuilderImpl& operator<<(T const& t) {
            stream << t;
            return *this;
        }

        operator std::basic_string<CharType>() const {
            return stream.str();
        }
    };
}

using StringBuilder = impl::StringBuilderImpl<char>;
using WStringBuilder = impl::StringBuilderImpl<wchar_t>;
```

`StringBuilderImpl` corresponds somewhat to `std::basic_[string/stringstream]` and takes the underlying character type as a template argument. Your former classes `StringBuilder` and `WstringBuilder` are now only aliases for certain template specializations, just as `std::[string/wstring]` and `std::[stringstream/wstringstream]` are.

*(In my code, `StringBuilderImpl` is kind of hidden away inside an `impl` namespace. If it serves your need, however, you could also make it part of the public interface of your program library, allowing further specifications such as `StringBuilderImpl<char16_t>`)*

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking / hoping for. Awesome.